# Derivative of sin(x) = cos(x) from first principles without using (a + h)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How can I prove the derivative of $\sin(x)$ = $\cos(x)$ using two x values `a` and `b` - where `b` approaches `a`.

The first step here would be:

$$\lim_{a\to b}\frac{\sin (b) - \sin(a)}{b-a}$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{ x}=1$?

Comment: [Sum the sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities).

Comment: @Andrei yes that's fine

Comment: @conditionalMethod Any more help on where to go from there? I found this problem in a textbook with no answers and have been working at it for about 3 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry but I'll use a notation that is more convenient for me to write in. Hope that's ok. The connection of course would be that $b=x$ and $a=x_0$

Consider the following: for every $x\neq x_o$ we have
$$
\frac{\sin (x)-\sin \left(x_{0}\right)}{x-x_{0}}=\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{x-x_{0}}{2}\right) \cdot \cos \left(\frac{x+x_{0}}{2}\right)}{x-x_{0}}=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{x-x_{0}}{2}\right)}{\frac{x-x_{0}}{2}} \cdot \cos \left(\frac{x+x_{0}}{2}\right)
$$

By the trig identity $
\sin \alpha+\sin \beta=2 \sin \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)
$. Now we substitute $y=\frac{x-x_{0}}{2}$, and see that:
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{x-x_{0}}{2}\right)}{\frac{x-x_{0}}{2}}=\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin y}{y}=1
$$
And:
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \cos \left(\frac{x+x_{0}}{2}\right)=\cos x_{0}
$$
After manipulation we arrived at limit of product, since both limits exist it'll be equal to the product of the limits, so:
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \frac{\sin (x)-\sin \left(x_{0}\right)}{x-x_{0}}=\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{x-x_{0}}{2}\right)}{\frac{x-x_{0}}{2}} \cdot \cos \left(\frac{x+x_{0}}{2}\right)=1 \cdot \cos x_{0}=\cos{(x_0)}
$$

As required.